# c++ replace values in linked list by changing pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

Having a problem with linked list. Need to create a method, which will replace data in list, by not creating a new element but by changing pointers. For now I have such method:

```
    void replaceValues(Node* head, int indexOne, int indexTwo)
 {
    Node* temporaryOne = NULL;
    Node* temporaryTwo = NULL;
    Node* temp = NULL;
    Node* current = head;
    int count = 0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (count == indexOne)
        {
            temporaryOne = current;
        }
        else if (count == indexTwo)
        {
            temporaryTwo = current;
        }
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    current = head;
    count = 0;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (count == indexOne)
        {
            head = temporaryTwo;
        }
        else if (count == indexTwo)
        {
            head = temporaryOne;
        }
        count++;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

I am sure, that exists a more simpler way, how to do it, but I don't fully understand, how it works...
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of writing a massive function, write two small utilities: One that removes an entry from the list without deleting it, and one that inserts an already existing entry in the list. Implementing your function given those will be a lot easier.

Comment: With "replace", do you mean "swap"?

Comment: All task is like this: Create function to replace element number n with element number
m. So, maybe swap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that with "replace" you actually mean "swap"/"exchange".

Some issues:

- The argument `head` should be passed by reference, as one of the nodes to swap may actually be that head node, and then `head` should refer to the other node after the function has done its job.
- The node *before* `temporaryOne` will need its `next` pointer to change, so you should stop your loops one step earlier in order to have access to that node and do that.
- In some cases `head` may need to change, but this is certainly not always the case, so doing `head = temporaryOne` or `head = temporaryTwo` is certainly not right. In most cases you'll need to link to the swapped node from the *preceding* node (see previous point).
- The `next` pointer of the node that is swapped will also need to change, as the node that follows it will be a different one than before.

As mentioned already in comments, it is advised to split the task into removals and insertions, as the fiddling with `next` pointers can get confusing when you try to cover all possible cases, notably making the distinction between the case where the two nodes are adjacent and when they are not.

Here are some functions that split the work into removal, insertion and finally exchanging nodes:

```
Node* removeNode(Node* &head, int index) {
    // If index is out of range, no node is removed, and function returns  nullptr
    // Otherwise the extracted node is returned.
    if (head == nullptr || index < 0) return nullptr;
    Node* current = head;
    if (index == 0) {
        head = head->next;
        current->next = nullptr;
        return current;
    }
    while (--index > 0) {
        current = current->next;
        if (current == nullptr) return nullptr;
    }
    Node* temp = current->next;
    if (temp != nullptr) {
        current->next = temp->next;
        temp->next = nullptr;
    }
    return temp;
}

void insertNode(Node* &head, Node* node, int index) {
    // If index is too large, node is inserted at the end of the list
    // If index is negative, node is inserted at the head of the list
    if (index <= 0 || head == nullptr) {
        node->next = head;
        head = node;
        return;
    }
    Node* current = head;
    while (--index > 0 && current->next != nullptr) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    node->next = current->next;
    current->next = node;
}

bool exchangeNodes(Node* &head, int indexOne, int indexTwo)
{
    // Returns true when successful, false when at least one index  
    // was out of range, or the two indexes were the same
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL || indexOne == indexTwo || indexOne < 0) return false;
    // To ensure the right order of operations, require the first index is the lesser:
    if (indexOne > indexTwo) return exchangeNodes(head, indexTwo, indexOne);
    Node* two = removeNode(head, indexTwo);
    if (two == nullptr) return false; // out of range
    Node* one = removeNode(head, indexOne);
    insertNode(head, two, indexOne);
    insertNode(head, one, indexTwo);
    return true;
}
```